# How would I say the imperative command "Heal!"?

Tags: imperative

In a fantasy setting, I'm looking for a magic spell word in Latin that translates to the imperative command "Heal!" that someone could point at someone sick and have them get better.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Good thing the magic spells in your fantasy world are in Latin, not in German, is all I'm saying...

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel, the pointing gesture would of course involve holding one's arm high with the palm facing downward toward the sick person, as if one is blessing them with the power radiating from the hand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Fī sānus!

Literally, "Become well!" Addressed to a woman, it would need to be *Fī sāna!*

This avoids a problem with verbs like *sānā* and *cūrā,* which suggest taking some sort of action, like administering a medicine, to make someone (yourself in this case) become well.

I think there must be something more idiomatically Latin than this, though.

Answer (score 4):

> Medice, cūrā tē ipsum!

is the famous proverb, quoted by Jesus in [Luke 4:23](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke+4%3A23&version=VULGATE), meaning "Physician, heal thyself!"

The primary meaning of [*cūrāre*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/curo#Latin) is "to take care of", "to take care that"; it's the root of English *curate.* But it has a secondary meaning of "heal"—it's also the root of English *cure.* You could put it into the imperative, *cūrā!*, but I believe it's a transitive verb, though: it needs an object. So, *Tē cūrā!* This suggests applying some art or method to heal oneself, though, like what a physician does. It may not be quite what you want, if you want to suggest magically becoming well.

Answer (score 2):

"Heal (somebody)" is "sana (aliquem)". "Heal" as in "to become healthy" is "corrige", albeit "corrige" can mean very different things.